# ScrollReveal 'no elements found'?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollreveal.js

I've been messing around with a few javascript libraries that might aid me in the creation of a portfolio website I look forward to creating. However, I have ran into an issue with the scrollreveal.js library. When I load the site (testing locally), I get this in the console `ScrollReveal: reveal on ".example" failed, no elements found.`

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div id="mainContent1">

<div class="example" data-scroll></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.example {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 150vh; //just to be able to scroll down for sr effect
}
```

Javascript:

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal ();
sr.reveal('.example');
```

I simply cannot get it to work, and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I've never used it but it sounds like there needs to be some content inside the 'example' div. ?

Comment: @wazz I thought this too, but the console is making it sound as though the div with an id of 'example' isn't there to begin with. I did have content within the div before and still got the same console message.

Comment: I just tried it in a fiddle and it appears to work. You have to scroll way down to the very bottom. (Make sure that comment in the css is gone or properly commented. `/* comment */`). https://jsfiddle.net/wazz/9f8o5m7g/8/

Comment: @wazz probably a browser issue, it works on fiddle as you've indicated, but not while testing locally on Chrome. Though, I have tried on multiple browsers and I can't get it to work on any of them (Chrome, IE (ew), Safari, FireFox, Opera, etc.)

Comment: Where is your link to ScrollReveal? Make sure it's just before your closing </body> tag. ... that's not the probem is it... nvmnd... or actually, maybe it is. Make sure it's not in the head.

Comment: @wazz I'll try that, I did previously have my script src for the scrollreveal in the head, I'll let ya know if that works

Comment: please post that as answer, the putting of the link to the library above the closing <body> tag, so I can put that as an answer thx

Comment: And make sure *your* script is after ScrollReveal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the link to the ScrollReveal library is just before your closing  tag. And make sure your script is after that.

If your script is at the top, it will be looking for elements that are not yet on the page.